# Grails setting metaclass properties on object reference

Tags: grails, groovy, metaclass

Using Grails domain objects, I've stumbled across a problem trying to set certain properties.

```
var stepchild=parent.children.find{ it.id==xInt };
stepchild.metaClass.birthMom=biologicalMothersName;

parent.children.each{child->
    //when it gets to stepchild no metaclass property birthMom exists....
}
```

Also custom errors do not get set on the referenced object

```
var stepchild=parent.children.find{ it.id==xInt };
stepchild.errors.rejectValue('parent',"Not biological parent");

parent.children.each{child->
    //when it gets to stepchild no errors....
}
```

I'm guessing find{} doesn't return a true reference to the child sub object of parent?

Answer (score 0):

For the way you are trying to set a property/attribute on the stepChild object, you should use the `MetaClass.setAttribute()` method:

```
stepchild.metaClass.setAttribute(stepChild,'birthMom', biologicalMothersName)
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, You haven't provided much code on what your domain objects look like. Is parent an actual attribute on the stepChild domain object?